# The resource cannot be found. Requested URL: /login.aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net

I created a new project Asp.net MVC 4 and when I run that occurs error like:

The resource cannot be found.

**Description**: HTTP 404. 
The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

**Requested** URL: /login.aspx

I was trying to solve by adding in web.config inside section appSettings a

```
<add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false" /> 
<add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false"/>
```

but it doesn't work.

Next I was trying to set in properties of the project in web section a Project Url but also it doesn't work.

Can anyone help me with it ?

Ps. I think it may be problem with IIS and permission.

Answer (score 0):

Is the page *Login.aspx" located in the same directory with the file, from where you are trying to redirect to that page?
U didn't try to do something like `~/Login.aspx`, if that page located in the root?

Comment: but i don't have even the file login.aspx in my project. I just created simple asp.net mvc basic project and i just added simple view called Index and controller to return this view.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me.

Try not only adding this:

```
<add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false" /> 
<add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false"/>
```

But also, change *web.config* in the *system.web* section:

```
<authentication mode="Forms" />
```

To this:

```
<authentication mode="Forms" >
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH"></forms>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
```